# Samba Domain Unavailable

Tags: samba, windows-10, netlogon

I have an Ubuntu machine that acts as an NT4 style PDC with samba 4.3.
Clients are all windows pro (7 an 10) machines and till now we haven't any problem in joining clients and log in domain users on our clients.
Now we bought a couple of new PCs  with windows 10 PRO and successfully joined them to domain. But when I attempt to log in with my account, it fails and I receive this message: "we can't sign in with this credential because your domain isn't available".
My PC is a windows 10 client too with the same OS Version number (1909) of the PC that can't log in, and I have no problem in logging.

Anyone has any idea about what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: Probably a DNS problem. But you should also check samba's logs to see if something else is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. Increasing samba log level I discovered that there was an issue with the machine account. So I remove it from the domain, then I deleted it from ldap, add it as a new machine and join it in the domain again. After that I'm able to login.